# Error in UiPath project with Outlook Mail Message: System.ArgumentException

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

[image]

I’m trying to use Get Outlook Mail Message to export date and subject of the email but I keep getting this error:

```
Source: Get Outlook Mail Messages
Message: The specified folder does not exist
Exception Type: System.ArgumentException

RemoteException wrapping System.ArgumentException: The specified folder does not exist 
   at UiPath.Mail.Activities.GetMailActivity.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

Comment: Don't post text as image

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your language that you use with Outlook. Set your `MailFolder` parameter to a value that exists.

So for English installation it is:

> Inbox

or German installation it is:

> Posteingang

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

in Outlook Express your email account is displayed as imap.gmail.com change its name with your email id or any name as you like

In Outlook Express
1 Right click on imap.gmail.com
2 Go to Properties
3 Click on Advanced then change its name as required
4 click ok

In Uipath
5 mention the same name in the "Account" property of "Get Outlook Mail Message" activity in UI path